# Trying to print a variable for a set amount of time

Tags: python

Can't get the "current" unix timestamp to update while the program is running.

```
import time

current = time.time()
dura = current + 1

count = 1
while current <= dura:
    while count == 1:
        print('hello')
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: You are only using `time.time()` once. If you want to get the current time at a later point, you have to call `time.time()` again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! could you explain what you intend to achieve . Because once you update "current"  using  current time, the execution of the while loop will be affected. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Based on [mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1)'s comment, the code would be:

```
import time
current = time.time()

dura = current + 1
count = 1
while current <= dura:
    current = time.time()
    while count == 1:
        print('hello')
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: The solution does not consist of replacing `time.time()` by `datetime.now()` or using `time.sleep()`. It's calling `datetime.now()` (or in the original code `time.time()`) *again* in the loop which solves the problem.